# Working with legend patches/symbology in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, legend

I am working with a legend in a map from ArcGIS 10.1. The map is used as a template and will be used many times to create different maps. The legend is used to show a soil type and its descriptor:

[image]

So, in other words, I have set my layer symbology to unique values, add all values, single field and I have turned off all the symbology so that the patches do not show up in the legend.

The solution I am looking for, is to avoid having to manually turn off the symbology all the time. I just want to 'Add All Values' and have the item and Description populate in the legend without the symbology patch.

I don't think there is a checkbox/button that does this in the layers properties symbology tab, but I was trying to figure out how to do this in the legend properties dialogue box. So far, I can't seem to figure it out. It seems like any of the styles under the Legend-->Properties-->Items tab requires a patch, label and description. There is no option to just choose the label and description. Am I missing it somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

It's a slight fudge but try setting **Width** and **Height** on the **Override default patch size** part of the **Legend Item** properties to be **very small but not zero** i.e. 0.001.  In my test it looks like the patch is either not there at all, or is too small to see.  If you set to 0 then patches return to original size.

[image]